# Sum / average of values at specific index in multiple sub arrays - jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have data in the form of an array that contains multiple sub-arrays - each sub-array contains multiple arrays that consist of two paired integers, a timestamp and a value. Example of array:

```
var data = [
  [
    [1519603200000, 17],
    [1519689600000, 20],
    [1519776000000, 16],
    [1519862400000, 21]
  ],
  [
    [1519603200000, 6],
    [1519689600000, 4],
    [1519776000000, 6],
    [1519862400000, 8]
  ]
]
```

What I need is the sum of all values (not timestamps) from arrays **in the first sub array only** i.e. data[0]

In the example above would be 17 + 20 + 16 + 21 = 74

I then need the average of these values for that sub array (presumably this could be calculated by dividing the total by data[0].length - 1)

I am struggling to select just the values and not the timestamps from each array pair.

Please can anybody suggest an efficient method of summing and averaging the values from the first subarray using jQuery, bearing in mind that my data may eventually contain several hundred [timestamp, value] pairs?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to sum the values at index 1 in your array.

```js
var data = [ [ [1519603200000, 17], [1519689600000, 20], [1519776000000, 16], [1519862400000, 21] ], [ [1519603200000, 6], [1519689600000, 4], [1519776000000, 6], [1519862400000, 8] ] ],
    sum = data[0].reduce((sum,a) => sum + a[1], 0),
    average = sum /data[0].length;
console.log(sum, average);
```

Answer (score 1):

DEMO:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var data = [
        [
          [1519603200000, 17],
          [1519689600000, 20],
          [1519776000000, 16],
          [1519862400000, 21]
        ],
        [
          [1519603200000, 6],
          [1519689600000, 4],
          [1519776000000, 6],
          [1519862400000, 8]
        ]
      ];
      var sum = 0;
      
      $(data[0]).each(function() {
        sum += $(this)[1];
        console.log("Added: ", $(this)[1]) 
      });
      
      console.log("Sum is:", sum);
      console.log("The average is:", sum / data[0].length)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`data` is an array, so you will use `data[0]` to get its first element. This element is also an array, so you will loop with `.each()` and sum the elements.

The average will be `sum / data[0].length`